# Applescript to toggle hyperlinks

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I'm trying to write an Applescript to toggle the hyperlinks in Microsoft word. (This is normally done by hitting Alt+F9).

Here's my script, but it doesn't work:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
        keystroke F9 using {option down}
end tell
```

That just gives me an error:

> "Expected end of line but found identifier"

If I use:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        keystroke F9 using {option down}
    end tell
end tell
```

it works but does nothing.

And if I use:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        keystroke "Hello"
    end tell
end tell
```

It just prints "Hello" in the applescript window. I need it to affect MS word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to script simulated keyboard shortcuts here. To toggle field codes (e.g. between the form `{HYPERLINK "http://www.stackoverflow.com"}` and actual hyperlinks), use this script:

```
# toggle field codes
# same as option + F9
# tested in Microsoft® Word 2008 for Mac v 12.2.3
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set theView to active window's active pane's view
    if (show field codes of theView) then
        set show field codes of theView to false
    else
        set show field codes of theView to true
    end if
end tell
```

Note that this will also switch other field codes, such as page numbers, off and on.